# Upload file with Retrofit 2.0

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm using this method to upload files to my server:

```
@Multipart
@POST("new")
Call<Response> send(@Part("myFile") byte[] file);
```

I have been reading and some people use `TypedFile` to do it, and maybe this is easier than send raw bytes like I'm doing.

`TypedFile` class is in `retrofit.mime` package. But I don't have it there. Has this package been removed from 2.0 version? Or do I have to add another dependency? If so, which one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In 2.0 you need to use RequestBody  instead of TypedFile. Get file with RequestBody

```
RequestBody file = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), path);
```

Use it in your request

```
@Multipart
@POST("new")
Call<Response> send(@Part("myFile") RequestBody file);
```

More info https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1063

Comment: Thanks. I'm gonna try it

Comment: @HellCat2405 how to upload multiple files using retrofit2.